# Magento 2.4.2- How to disable two factor authentication?

Tags: magento, magento2

I just installed Magento 2.4.2 on my website. However, at the admin panel, I can see that 2FA is enabled by default. How can I disable 2FA in Magento and login to my admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this via the command line:

```
bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/enable 0
bin/magento cache:flush
```

alternatively you can disable the module altogether:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Great !! Thank you very much. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the MarkShust_DisableTwoFactorAuth extension: https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth. It will add the missing toggle to turn 2FA on or off from the admin.

```
bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/enable 0
bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/enable_for_api_token_generation 0
```